# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') in react.js (pretty basic code but I couldn't understand any answer in other posts)

Tags: reactjs

I don't really understand (getting started on react and every answer on this topic really didn't help for it had too many things) because I tried onMouseOver={console.log(this.state)} and it showed it without any problem.

```
class GenresInDb extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            genresList: [],
            genreBg: "",
        }
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        window.fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/genres')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(genres => {
                this.setState({ genresList: genres.data })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
    changeBg() {
        if(this.state.genreBg === ""){
            this.setState({
                genreBg: "bg-secondary"
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                genreBg: ""
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {/*<!-- Categories in DB -->*/}
                <div className="col-lg-6 mb-4">
                    <div className="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div className="card-header py-3">
                            <h6 onMouseOver={this.changeBg} className="m-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Genres in Data Base</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div className={`card-body ${this.state.genreBg}`}>
                            <div className="row">
                                {this.state.genresList.map((genre, index) => {
                                    return <Genre {...genre} key={index} />
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I expected the background color to change when I hovered with the mouse use the setState yet apparently my this.state inside my method is undefined.

Comment: Could you share the running code (on CodeSandbox, StackBlitz,...) for easier debuging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue came from `this.state.genreBg` in function `changeBg()`.

This is because the `this` keyword ***(1)*** in scope of function `changeBg()` is not the same as those other `this` keywords ***(2)*** in scope of function `GenresInDb()` (the `<GenresInDb>` component).

***Why (1) and (2) are not the same?***

> The ‘this’ keyword typically references a JavaScript element depending on the scope or context of its use.

There are **Global ‘this’ scope** and **Function ‘this’ scope**.

> ...When using strict mode, "`this`" in a function will refer to it’s explicit value, and if "`this`" hasn’t been explicitly set then "`this`" will be `undefined`.

And maybe you're in `React.StrictMode`, so that the `this` in function `changeBg()` are `undefined`.

You can refer to [this post](https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480) to understand more about `this` keyword. It's quite fuzzy for newbies to understand.

---

Back to your problem, to solve that, you only need to change function into **arrow function**.

```
changeBg = () => {
    if(this.state.genreBg === ""){
        this.setState({
            genreBg: "bg-secondary"
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            genreBg: ""
        })
    }
}
```